# Recommended carrying bag for macbook pro 15.4"

Tags: macbook-pro

What are some recommended carrying cases for MBP 15.4"

Comment: Buying recommendations are off-topic as per the FAQ (see the site's title bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BrentHaven](http://www.brenthaven.com/MacBook-Cases) makes amazing cases.  I used a backpack of theirs for four years of school for my MacBook Pro (the first Intel one they released), and it performed admirably.  Superb protection.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Really loved their Brenthaven ProStyle Slim Pack. Will order that one and try it out.